# Can I add my own property in 'this' of xAxis labels formatter function in High Charts?

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with xAxis labels formatter.
At this link "http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter" highchart api show some additional properties for "this" (chart, axis, value, isFirst, isLast) and get different by this.value. But in my case have many item in categories same value (http://jsfiddle.net/xfetaarL). So is possible for adding more additional properties (ex: id ) for separate item and then we can use that "id" in formatter function ?

```
function() {
  var id = this.id // this is my own property that I want to add
  return this.value;
}
```

Thanks for any your help. :wink:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change format for `xAxis.categories`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xfetaarL/2/

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: 'Foobar',
            id: '#1'
        }, {
            name: 'Foobar',
            id: '#2'
        }, {
            name: 'Foobar',
            id: '#3'
        }],

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<a href="' + categoryLinks[this.value.name] + '">' + this.value.name + ' dhlId:' + this.value.id + '</a>';
            }
        }
    },
```

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Why once I have implemented categories array on an X axis my labels are shown in 45 degrees. Any idea?

Comment: It's the default behaviour when there isn't enough space. See [`xAxis.labels.autoRotation`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.autoRotation) option

Comment: Well, after changing to userOptions for custom properties it stopped doing it.